# How to restore recyclerview position on screen rotates when using PagedListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I am using PagedListAdapter and PageKeyedDataSource from android paging library. I want to restore recyclerview position after screen rotates. How can I achieve this?
setInitialLoadKey on LivePagedListBuilder doesn't effect to PageKeyedDataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to achieve this behavior with PageKeyedDataSource. Instead I have to implement PositionalDataSource